# Geth does not recognize GPU drivers on Debian

Tags: linux, ati, ethereum

I have installed proprietary AMD drivers from http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86_64 and the AMD APP SDK for OpenCL from http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/. I've also built go-ethereum from source with the OpenCL flag. However, when I attempt to set up the GPU's in geth, I get:

```
aaron@o2:~$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cypress PRO [Radeon HD 5850]
02:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cypress PRO [Radeon HD 5850]
aaron@o2:~$ aticonfig --list-adapters
* 0. 01:00.0 AMD Radeon HD 5800 Series
  1. 02:00.0 AMD Radeon HD 5800 Series

* - Default adapter
aaron@o2:~$ Documents/go-ethereum/build/bin/geth gpuinfo
=============================================
============ OpenCL Device Info =============
=============================================
Platform id              0
Platform Name            AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Platform Vendor          Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
Platform Version         OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (1912.5)
Platform Extensions      cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices
Platform Profile         FULL_PROFILE

Device error (check your GPU drivers) : cl: Device Not Found
```

Could someone give me pointers on how to troubleshoot the driver configuration, or how to test whether an OpenCL driver was installed properly?

Comment: The question is off-topic on stack overflow, which deals with **programming** questions. However, there are other communities in the stack exchange network who may deal with such stuff. Try UNIX, Superuser, etc.

Comment: Try [Ethereum Stackexchange](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/) :-)